# How does the github UI navigate directories without postbacks?

Tags: javascript, html, url, navigation, query-string

When navigating through my repo directories on [github.com](http://www.github.com), I noticed that it uses cool javascript effects to switch between directory views without ever causing a postback, and yet the url changes nice and RESTfully: `http://../tree/master/dir7` -> `http://../tree/master/dir7/dir4`.

Whenever I have to keep track of navigation with javascript, I've always had to resort to hash arguments in the address bar. `http://...page#new-javascript-location`

How do they do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider